# Django Url unknown space

Tags: python, django

My urls.py is

```
   urlpatterns = [
         url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
         url(r'^chat/', include('chat.urls'))
  ]
```

And My chat/urls.py is

```
   urlpatterns = [
          #url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
          url(r'input/$', views.input , name='input'),

        ]
```

Now when I try to hit the link http://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/input/ i got the error page not found 404.

It seems like there is an unknown space are after chat/  input.
The Question why these spaces are there and how to remove them
Screen shot of error message is here

View Code in as following

```
  def input(request):
       input = request.POST.get('msg', None)
      data ={
           'output': 'hi',
       }
     return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: Can you show your view?

Comment: view code is added.

Answer (score 3):

add the `caret ^` sign before the url start or else it wont work

```
url(r'^input/$', views.input , name='input'),
```

or else

change this line

```
url(r'^chat/', include('chat.urls'))
```

to

```
url(r'^chat/$', include('chat.urls'))
```

Comment: I did the same as above (not adding the ^) and it works